# В вторую активити приложения нужно по-новой получать новый идентификатор баннера (в AdMob) или можно работать с первым идентификатором?

Tags: android, admob, реклама

Имеется один рекламный баннер от adMob. Работает нормально.

В вторую активити приложения нужно по-новой получать новый идентификатор баннера (в AdMob) или можно работать с первым идентификатором?

Здесь работает принцип: новый баннер - новый идентификатор?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать один. Разные id нужно делать если хотите получить статистику какой экран больше зарабатывает.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать уникальный баннер на каждую Activity. Количество кода не увеличится, но вы получите более гибкую настройку и более точную статистику.